# Get the position of the windows start menu

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

I'm writing an app in Python that automatically moves stuff around. How do I get the position of the windows start menu bar, so I can account for it in my calculations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, found it. `GetMonitorInfo`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144901(VS.85).aspx . Here is an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162826(VS.85).aspx .

Answer (score 1):

When you ask for the work area, the taskbar area is automatically excluded.

```
System.Parameters.WorkArea
```

or Use interop to

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA, ...)`
```

and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

To get the rectangle use [SHAppBarMessage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762108(VS.85).aspx).  You would do the following in C++:

```
APPBARDATA abd = {0};
SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETTASKBARPOS, &abd);
```

And then `abd.rc` would contain the rectangle.  You just have to do the pywin32 equivilent.

Please note that GetMonitorInfo() will give you the working area, which is desktop - appbars, but the Task Bar is not the only appbar that might exist.